# Pseudo-polynomial algorithm for Bin-Packing with fixed number of bins

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, dynamic-programming

I'm looking for a pseudo-polynomial algorithm for the Bin-Packing Problem for a fixed number of bins $k$. I know we can use dynamic programming when the number of different sizes is fixed size since then all feasible bins can be computed in pseudo-polynomial time.

But how do we do that for a fixed number of bins? I read that it can be done by dynamic programming in $O(n^{O(k)})$ time but I don't see how and sadly it doesn't give a reference or explains how. 
Every approach I tried, resulted in exponential time in $n$. Has anyone an idea?